# Not able to git pull in android studio 3.6

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.6

I am getting error as mentioned below:

> Update failed
>                     Invocation failed Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
>                     at org.jetbrains.git4idea.nativessh.GitNativeSshAskPassXmlRpcClient.handleInput(GitNativeSshAskPassXmlRpcClient.java:34)
>                     at org.jetbrains.git4idea.nativessh.GitNativeSshAskPassApp.main(GitNativeSshAskPassApp.java:30)
>                     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
>                     at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendRequest(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:231)
>                     at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendXmlRpc(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:90)
>                     at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:72)
>                     at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:194)
>                     at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:185)
>                     at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:178)
>                     at org.jetbrains.git4idea.nativessh.GitNativeSshAskPassXmlRpcClient.handleInput(GitNat

In previous versions, I managed to fix it like this:

AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> Git -> SSH Executable and changed from Native to Built-in and it started working. See UI here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCvHA.png

But in android studio 3.6, I don't see above option in settings.

[image]

I have also tested the git using **Test** button at top right. Git is executing successfully.

[image]

Comment: I also have this issue. It's terrible and I can't find any workaround right now. I found a Google issue that was reopened few days ago: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124680708

Comment: Thanks for the issue tracker link. I have added a comment there with details

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Me too.
I was going to add a new ssh certificate using this tutorial from git...
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent


But in my case i found that just doing step 3...
Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent
$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa

and then trying android studio seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: I was just typing a question describing me having exactly this issue and then I read "Similar questions" ...

Comment: I also wanted to add that `git pull` and `git push` is working from the terminal, executed in the project directory.

Comment: The same on a windows machine. On the mac, reset ssh helped.

Comment: I want to confirm that thanks to @aidanmack I was able to fix the same issue.

Comment: But what if I don't have an SSH key and I'm using password authentication?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved in Android Studio 3.6.1. I verified it by updating from 3.6 to 3.6.1 and git is working as expected

You can find release notes [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/02/android-studio-361-available.html). It says

> Git version control authentication issue resolved
>
> In the initial release of Android Studio 3.6, operations requiring
>   authentication in Git version control were broken in the IDE. This bug
>   has been fixed in 3.6.1. See Issue #124680708 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Go to -

```
Android Studio -> Setting-> GitHub
```

If you can't login using **username** and **password** try to get a **Token** from **GitHub** from here -

https://github.com/settings/tokens/new

and then generate new token if you don't have one. And finally login with **Token**

[image]